# Create new project without MainStoryboard in Xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode

I found this solution

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jpe-rrBHRSU

but when i run app, my app don't show viewcontroller
[image]

i tried to many solution but no success

Comment: Try this [tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-productions/ios-start-a-project-without-storyboard-xcode-12-253d785af5e70)

Comment: open your Plist file and delete this key completely : Scene Configuration, also delete all codes in your appDelegate but the first function. and write this to you ViewController to make sure you have it. view.backgroundColor = .red